# Tensorflow sess.run() returns nothing

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I've been running a program located here: 
https://github.com/dennybritz/cnn-text-classification-tf
and the base code works fine with the posted example. But, I tried to split new data into a train/test split and then it gives me errors. The program trains on the train data I give it, but come evaluation time I get this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "./eval.py", line 81, in  correct_predictions = float(sum(all_predictions == y_test)) 

TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable`
```

From the `eval.py` code I located where the problem is in this loop:

```
    for x_test_batch in batches:
        batch_predictions = sess.run(predictions, {input_x: x_test_batch, dropout_keep_prob: 1.0})
        all_predictions = np.concatenate([all_predictions, batch_predictions])
```

Wherein `sess.run` returns nothing and `batch_predictions` becomes an empty array, leading to a value error later on. Also of note:

- batch_predictions is always empty.
- x_test_batch is non-empty for every batch.
- all_predictions is also always empty.

I brought up the issue with the github owner but he recommended I trace through execution. This is my first time using Tensorflow and I am unable to access their website. If anyone can

1. Tell me what my issue is

or

2. Tell me how to trace through the graph execution to find it

I would be endlessly appreciative. Thank you to anyone who reads this!

Answer (score 0):

you say sess.run does not return anything, perhaps you could print x_test_batch before running sess.run and look whats inside, perhaps its empty, which is not your intention i think

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified:

batch_predictions is always empty.

x_test_batch is non-empty for every batch.

all_predictions is also always empty.

Comment: perhaps all_predictions must be initialize with some value first ? somewhere where you put in your example-data ?

Comment: The base-done with the example works flawlessly out of the box though. Would initializing for one dataset and not the other be impactful? And if so:  why? 

Also thank you for helping me, I really appreciate this :D

Comment: if this Variable/placeholder is used in any op, then it must be initialized or the operation can not work, with what should it operate then ? is sess.run(predictions used in the sections which are running well ?

Comment: It is initialized as an empty array initially. When the code runs with the example it fills with a series of predictions to classify the text, but because the sess.run() isn't returning anything it ends as an empty array after processing all the batches, where no batch is empty.

Comment: then y_test is not initialized, i mean that because of the error you provide: File "./eval.py", line 81, in  correct_predictions = float(sum(all_predictions == y_test))        or wrongly initalized with bool?

Comment: y_test is initalized to an array of 1s and 0s predictions.

Is there a chance that the sess didn't get configured correctly? Do you know how I would be able to check this?